# Matlab recover function workspace after error

Tags: matlab, workspace

When an error occurs inside some function, is it possible to recover it's workspace and/or continue the execution after fixing the issue?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/300132?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: `dbstop if error`?

Comment: @hbaderts ohh, nice!